# Rxjs pass data after error on Observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, observable

I know that by definition when an Observable is **Completed** or it has an **Error** it became **cold** and you cannot pass data to it.
So if you want to pass data after the **Error** you need to create a new Observable.


I'm just wondering if you can somehow restore the Observable after the **Error**, as it makes more sense for me to restore it instead to create a new one with the same functionality ?

Ex :

```
const subject = new Rx.Subject();

subject.subscribe(
  data => console.log(data), 
  error => console.log('error')
);

subject.next('new data');
subject.next('new data2');

subject.error('error');

subject.next('new data3');
```

The **new data3** is not sent as it has an error before that.
Working example : https://jsbin.com/sizinovude/edit?js,console

PS : I want the subscriber to have the error and also send data after, looks like the only way is to create a new Observable and subscribe to the new one after the error.

Answer (score 1):

No, my understanding is that you cannot emit further data to subscribers after the observable errors.

The *Observable Termination* section in the [*Observable Contract*](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html) states:

> When an Observable does issue an OnCompleted or OnError notification, the Observable may release its resources and terminate, and its observers should not attempt to communicate with it any further.

This suggests to me that if you call `next` after `error`, any subscribers will not receive the value, as they will have unsubscribed upon receipt of the error notification. This is also mentioned in the *Observable Termination* section:

> When an Observable issues an OnError or OnComplete notification to its observers, this ends the subscription.

Comment: So lets say that you want a retry button for an http request, when it has an error you want to create a new request. For this you cannot pass more data to that Observable and you need to create a new one and subscribe to that ?

Comment: Resubscribe to the observable that emitted the error. That's what the [retry](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retry) operators do.

Answer (score 0):

One strategy could be to handle well know errors (i.e. data validation) in observables by creating an observable that is the error stream.

I use .NET but I am sure you get the idea:

```
class UseSubject
{
    public class Order
    {            
        private DateTime? _paidDate;

        private readonly Subject<Order> _paidSubj = new Subject<Order>();
        private readonly Subject<Error> _errorSubj = new Subject<Error>();
        public IObservable<Order> Paid { get { return _paidSubj.AsObservable(); } }
        public IObserble<Error> Error {get {return _errorSubj.AsObservable();
}}
        public void MarkPaid(DateTime paidDate)
        {
            if (!paidDate.isValid){_errorSubj.OnNext(New Error("invalid paidDate")); return}
            _paidDate = paidDate;                
            _paidSubj.OnNext(this); // Raise PAID event
        }
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        var order = new Order();
        order.Paid.Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("Paid")); // Subscribe
        order.Error.Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("Error"));
        order.MarkPaid(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```